# How set columns to fixed size in Winforms ListView with view style View.SmallIcon

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have a C# Winforms application and am using the ListView control. When I set the View property to View.SmallIcon the icons are not aligned into fixed size columns. The items are spread all over the place.

Is there a property to set on the ListView control to cause fixed sized columns in the SmallIcon view.

**Update:**
Below are screenshots depicting the problem I am running into. Screenshot #1 shows Windows Explorer where file names are fixed in width and ellipsis are introduced. While technically there may not be any actual columns in play, the icons are aligned in "columnar" type layout.
[image]
<sub>(source: [barramsoft.com](http://www.barramsoft.com/pub/images/ListViewSmallIcons2.png))</sub>

Screenshot #2 shows what I am running into. The icons have a not so pretty layout:
[image]
<sub>(source: [barramsoft.com](http://www.barramsoft.com/pub/images/ListViewSmallIcons.png))</sub>

Comment: The SmallIcon view doesn't use columns.

Comment: At the very least it gives such an appearance. I have included screenshots to make the issue clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754006/listview-tile-layout-problem-vb-net

Answer (score 1):

The only view that uses columns is the "Details" view.

The "Small Icon" view is the same as the "Large Icon" view, except with smaller icons. The icons can be positioned all over the control. You can play with this for yourself in Windows Explorer by changing the view; it uses a ListView control.

If you want to force the icons to line up in nice little rows, combine the [`Alignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.alignment.aspx) property with the [`AutoArrange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.autoarrange.aspx) property.

Set `Alignment` to either `ListViewAlignment.Top` or `ListViewAlignment.Left`, and `AutoArrange` to `true` to keep the icons automatically arranged in this position.

You can do this either in the designer or via code:

```
myListView.Alignment   = ListViewAlignment.Top;
myListView.AutoArrange = true;
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not appear to resolve the issue I have. I have updated my question with screenshots to better show what I am running into.

Comment: @Elan: It's doing the exact same thing in both screenshots. The problem is just that some of your captions are too long to fit. See Hans's comment for a way to fix that, increasing the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try freeware [Better ListView Express component](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express), it shows items in SmallIcon view always aligned and exactly like the Windows Explorer does.

You can also display column headers in all views (not only Details), which is not possible in .NET ListView.

ComponentOwl also offers a full version with many extra features.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.  I solved it by adding a column to the ListView using `fileNamesListView.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader());` and then setting `fileNamesListView.Columns[0].Width` to the width of the longest item text and its image.  The disadvantage is that all columns are the width of the widest column.

```
private void PopulateListView(List<string> fileNames)
{
    using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
        int longestTextWidth = 0;
        int longestTextIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Count; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileNames[i]);
            item.ImageIndex = 0; // Do whatever you do to choose the image.
            fileNamesListView.Items.Add(item);

            // Find the longest file name.
            int textWidth = Size.Round(g.MeasureString(fileNames[i], fileNamesListView.Font)).Width;
            if (textWidth > longestTextWidth)
            {
                longestTextWidth = textWidth;
                longestTextIndex = i;
            }
        }

        // Find the width of the image used.
        int imageWidth = filesImageList.Images[fileNamesListView.Items[longestTextIndex].ImageIndex].Width;

        fileNamesListView.Columns[0].Width = longestTextWidth + imageWidth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by controlling the text length as below :

```
   int max_length = 30; // you can use any value here

   ListViewItem l = lsvLocalFile.Items.Add("some text value");
   l.ImageIndex = index_of_smallimagelist;
   if (l.Text.Length > max_length) 
       l.Text = l.Text.Remove(max_length - 3) + "...";
   else
       l.Text = l.Text.PadRight(max_length);
```