# Listview Backgroundcolor over entire row like in a Listbox

Tags: c#, listview, listbox, selection

I have a problem with a ListView in C#. I'm using it instead of a ListBox so I can change the BackroundColor of an item. The ListView feature Colums is set to listing.

Now my problem is that when I change the Backroundcolor it isn't over the full row like when I'm selecting an item in a Listbox. Is there a possibility of changing this?

Answer (score 3):

Set this property:

```
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```

then go into the Columns collection of the ListView control and set each `Width` property to -2.

If the ListView control gets resized with the form, you would have to reset those column widths again.  Try something like this:

```
private void listView1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  foreach (ColumnHeader ch in listView1.Columns) {
    ch.Width = -2;
  }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, but when I set the FullRowSelect setting to true and the colums setting to tile it works, but the tiles are much to far away from each other. Is there a possibility to put them closer to each other?
Thanks for the Answer!

Comment: @PhilippThi This worked for me when I had the `View = Details` set.  It wouldn't work for `List` or `Tile` because those are wrapping styles — the object isn't meant to cover the full width of the control.  I didn't try it, but here's a link regarding [tile spacing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2754416/719186).